# How to control High read latency in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have set up a Cassandra With 3 node . At the client end I am using Datasatx java driver, my query is like

```
Select Abc from Cassandra where key =a and cluster_column<=10 limit 1;
```

As we can see in the above query I want to have the greatest  "cluster_column"  which is less than 10. 
I have wide rows . So when the data grows across the rows the Read latency is increasing.

I am using only key cache and level-compaction strategy. the MemTable size is kept as 2048 MB.

What parameter  I can  tweak to have lower read latency at the server level.

Please respond

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much RAM do your nodes have, and what are the JVM's MAX_HEAP_SIZE and HEAP_NEWSIZE set to?

Comment: What is CLUSTERING ORDER for the table?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 its config is Intel Xeon 2 * quad Core/64 GB RAM/800 GB*6 HDD

Comment: @MikhailStepura its clustering order is decreasing.

Comment: @Sarkar decreasing? Probably "increasing" should make more sense. The smallest values will be in the begging of a row, and your queries like "cluster_column<=10" will be more effective.

Comment: @MikhailStepura i think you misinterpreted me. I mean to say largest value of all the value less than 10. for example if i have 1,7.9. as Cluster_column name then I should get 9. That's why i override the default clustering order. I guess this time you are getting my point.

Comment: @Sarkar I got your point. Did you try to trace your queries? What does TRACING tell you?

Comment: @MikhailStepura I have not traced it. Actually i don't know how to do it when i am firing cql quries by using datastax driver. Will ypu please suggest...?

Comment: @Sarkar take a look at http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/tracing_t.html or http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute . Or you can even trace your queries in cqlsh - http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: @MikhailStepura thanks for the link. It was quite helpful . i will trace the result and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, on matching the partition key the **entire row is fetched** and then the subsequent filters are applied.
A single row in Cassandra can be **more than one row** you see in a CQL table, depending on your (composite) primary key.

In your case, if you perform select query on a small subset of columns very often, you can use one of these solutions:

1. **Change your partition key** to have more that one column. This will make your row skinny.

   Make sure you add columns that are always used in queries to your composite primary key. And select your primary key columns carefully as partition keys only support equals and in conditions.
2. **Create another table with a subset of columns** your query often. This will reduce the size of each Cassandra row, hence improving your latency.

I recommend you read [this blog post](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/wide-rows-in-cassandra-cql/) to get a better understanding of wide rows in Cassandra and read [this post](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/11/05/breaking-down-the-cql-where-clause/) to understand the restrictions on Where clause